# Select one row, each one id in sql query for odoo

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, odoo-8

I have a table like this:

```
 ID |     Cost     | Month |  Year  |
-------------------------------------
1081|     13000    |   5   |  2017  |
1081|     13500    |   9   |  2016  |
1081|     21000    |   2   |  2016  |
1229|     6500     |   7   |  2017  |
1229|     7800     |   5   |  2016  |
1312|    110000    |   8   |  2017  |
1312|    120000    |   5   |  2017  |
1312|     99000    |   5   |  2016  |
```

I've tried this:

```
select id, year, month, avg(cost) as Avg Cost
from price_history
group by id, year, month
order by id, year desc, month desc
```

How I can show the latest data like this:

```
 ID |     Cost     | Month |  Year  |
-------------------------------------
1081|     13000    |   5   |  2017  |
1229|     6500     |   7   |  2017  |
1312|    110000    |   8   |  2017  |
```

Comment: I don't understand from example of your output - Do you need AVG cost or what?

Comment: I just want latest data / row based on month and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, year, month, cost
  from (
    select id, year, month, cost,
           row_number() over(partition by ID order by year desc, month desc) as RN
      from price_history
 ) X
 where RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of the `RIGHT`/`LEFT`, `MAX` and concatenation functions to get your dates correctly grouped.

```
SELECT "ID", AVG("Cost") AS "Avg Cost", RIGHT(MAX("Year"::text || "Month"::text),1) AS "Month", LEFT(MAX("Year"::text || "Month"::text),4) AS "Year"
FROM price_history
GROUP BY "ID"
ORDER BY "ID"
```

Output

```
ID   Avg Cost           Month Year
1081 15833.333333333332 5     2017
1229 7150               7     2017
1312 109666.66666666667 8     2017
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3ebe7/20/0

Or with `ROUND`ing:

```
SELECT "ID", ROUND(AVG("Cost")) AS "Avg Cost", RIGHT(MAX("Year"::text || "Month"::text),1) AS "Month", LEFT(MAX("Year"::text || "Month"::text),4) AS "Year"
FROM price_history
GROUP BY "ID"
ORDER BY "ID"
```

Output

```
ID   Avg Cost Month Year
1081 15833    5     2017
1229 7150     7     2017
1312 109667   8     2017
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3ebe7/21/0

Comment: what if cost not average?

Comment: @FadhelJMuhammad ?? You asked for the Average cost?

Comment: No, i just want get latest data. I was edited column to cost

Comment: @FadhelJMuhammad And I would know that how? You didn't say that in your question.

Comment: Sorry, if my question gets you confused. Thanks for your answers :)